# Processing a binary Plist

Tags: iphone

Can someone please let me know the difference between normal plist and binary plist and how they are different processing wise? Is there anything extra I need to do to process a binary plist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary plists are not stored in human-readable XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>SUFeedURL</key>
        <string>http://www.hedgewars.org/download/appcast.xml</string>
        <key>SUHasLaunchedBefore</key>
        <true/>
        <key>SULastCheckTime</key>
        <date>2010-11-15T22:00:36Z</date>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Instead, they’re stored using Apple’s private methods, resulting in lower filesize. That example (preferences from Hedgewars) is 378 bytes, but in binary format is 162 bytes.

The good news is that built-in tools, such as [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/), will be able to use these formats interchangeably. Using other methods, such as [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)’s [`-arrayWithContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-CBHBIGBI) method, ought to work as well.

To convert between the two, you can use the [`plutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html) app, which is in `/usr/bin` if installed on your Mac. Here’s an example:

```
plutil -convert xml1 /path/to/your/plist.plist
```

That will convert the plist at the given path to XML. Valid formats are (for now) `xml1` and `binary1`.

Be sure to check out the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i), too.